# STM32 supplied with overvoltage

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, stm32, components

###### Issue

Accidentaly I plugged my [STM32F407ZGT6](https://github.com/mcauser/BLACK_F407ZG) on 15V for approximatedly 1s while changing some wires around. After the incident, I plugged the board to the computer and it still gets recognized, debugs and runs normally, **for as long as my external 3.3V source is supplying to the circuit**.

When the STM32 is plugged without the extrernal power supply to the computer via [knockoff ST-Link/V2](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1CeYdfER1BeNjy0Fmq6z0wVXa0.jpg), the STM32 board LEDs get dim and give the impression to be fadding away. Similarly, the LED on the ST-Link barely lights up. The board is still recognized though. When connected solely through the power supply, all the LEDs are fine, including the one on the ST-Link.

Now my question: it seems to me that the problem is more likely to be with the ST-Link. Is that initial guess correct, based on the information I just shared? How can I start to analyse this and find what got burnt?

###### Other specifications

My STM32 board is currently hooked up to:

- [Vonder PVT 120I power supply](https://www.rocfer.com.br/pode-ser-aplicado-nas-seguintes-parafusadeira-vonder) 15V and 0,4A
- 2x 100k trimpots
- 1x MMA8452Q accelerometer
- 1x LED
- 2x 47 resistors
- 1x [FTDI232](https://img.joomcdn.net/144b0966fa826188d22b0ac8f004248741c35698_original.jpeg)

###### Schematics

This is the closest circuit I could find to the ST-Link/V2:
[image]

And this is the circuit of the STM32 board (see in more details [here](https://github.com/mcauser/BLACK_F407ZG/blob/master/docs/STM32F407ZGT6_schematics.pdf))
[image]

Comment: You could have a fault with the STM board that's making it draw higher current.  If your usual power supply can source that and the ST-Link can't, then it's not the fault of the ST-Link.  Was the ST-Link exposed to this over voltage?  What input to the STM board was exposed to the over voltage?  I'm assuming it was a raw power input that's regulated on the board, because I'd expect that exposing the chip's 3.3V inputs to 15V would let the smoke out.

Comment: The ST-Link was connected to the JTag pins, but it wasn't connected to the UBS port, if I remember correctly. And the only inputs of the STM directly exposed to the 15V were the 3.3V and GND. And I'm not sure where it would be regulated, tho. I surely do not have a circuit to regulate it.

Comment: And it used to work, before, when powered by the ST-Link?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, everything would work fine. Depending on how many things were attached to it, the LED would lower in intensity but not as much as now

Comment: Sounds likely the chip is damaged and drawing excess current then. Whether any particular functions continue to operate, or the whole thing ends up toast, who knows, but out of 15V when the device likely breaks down at 4-4.5V, you're lucky it responds in any way at all!

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah, I had an ESP32 and another MMA attached when that happened and they didn't make it. I wonder if in any way they acted as some sort of protection...

Comment: Very likely so!